# Why doesn't Constructor/virtual destructor with braced initializer list work?

Tags: c++, constructor, virtual-destructor

Why doesnt the following code compile?

```
#include <vector>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    { }

    virtual ~Foo()
    { }

    std::vector<int> aVec;
};


Foo bar =
{
    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
};
```

While following code compiles:

```
#include <vector>

class Foo
{
public:

    /*Foo()
    { }

    virtual*/ ~Foo()
    { }

    std::vector<int> aVec;
};


Foo bar =
{
    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
};
```

Along with the reference to language rules, please elaborate on the rationale behind those rules.

Why does the existence of contructor and virtual destructor stops from initializing?

Comment: When asking about an error compiling, please include the compiler error.

Comment: Are you trying to disregard the class constructors?

Answer (score 5):

Because `Foo` is of class type, such that the braced init list is seen as an [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). This requires, among others, that the class does not have explicit constructors or virtual members:

> Aggregate initialization is a form of list-initialization, which
>   initializes aggregates. An aggregate is one of the following types:
>
> class type (typically, struct or union), that has...
>
> - no private or protected non-static data members
> - no user-provided, inherited, or explicit (since C++17) constructors (explicitly defaulted or deleted constructors are allowed)
> - no virtual, private, or protected base classes
> - no virtual member functions
> - default member initializers

Answer (score 5):

The form of list initialization you are using is known as [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). It's used for aggregate type. One of the requirements for a type to qualify as an aggregate is that it has no user provided constructors.

By providing a constructor, the compiler will try to match the list initialization to one of the defined constructors. It will prefer a constructor taking a single [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list). Since you do not provide one, it will try to find a constructor whos arguments match those provided by your initialization list. Since the only constructor is the default constructor which takes no arguments, no match is found.

Answer (score 1):

`Foo bar = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } };` is [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). It is only defined for arrays and "aggregate" class types. Adding any constructor or virtual member means the type is not aggregate.